# How can I start second activity and close the first?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want launch a second Activity when i touch a button and close this first activity... How can I do?

I did this to lauch second Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceConexion.class);
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: just add `finish();` after `startActivity(i);`...

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ServiceConexion.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually on start of new activity the previous activity will be paused until you either return to that activity using Back button (unless history is disabled for that specific activity) or it will await to be killed when app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
finish();
```

It's basically the finish() that closes the activity.